# PHP Array : a function that return next object in array (with array and current object param)?

Tags: php, arrays, list, iterator

My question is : is there a function that return next object in array (with array and current object param) ?
Can you help me to code the best way ?

```php
function get_next($array, $currentObject) {

    .... ?
    return $nextObject;
}
```

Comment: No, but it should only take a few minutes to write one

Comment: Beware that any uses of this function don't turn into [Schlemiel the Painter's alogirthm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? Paint us the bigger picture please, Schlemiel.

Comment: it sounds like generators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_next($array, $currentObject) {
    $key = array_search($currentObject, $array);
    if($key!==false) {
       $key++; // Work only on numbers and letter
       if(isset($array[$key])) {
          return $array[$key];
       } else {
          return null;
       }
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, this

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array) && $array[i] != $currentObject; $i++);
```

I would not put this into function at all, I would put it were I am calling that function but here is your function:

```
function get_next($array, $currentObject) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array) && $array[i] != $currentObject; $i++);
    return array[$i];
}
```

Simple linear and works in any occasion.